# Codeigniter Database Error which is not allowing me to access my website

Tags: php

This is my databse.php file. I am not able to connect to the database using this connection settings. Please help me debug this error.
Thank you.

The error displayed is:
A Database Error Occurred
Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 125

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
    $db['default']['username'] = 'root';
    $db['default']['password'] = '';
    $db['default']['database'] = '******';
    $db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
    $db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
    $db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
    $db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
    $db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
    $db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
    $db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
    $db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
    $db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
    $db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
    $db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;

    $db['online']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
    $db['online']['username'] = '******';
    //$db['online']['username'] = '******';
    $db['online']['password'] = '******';
    $db['online']['database'] = '******';
    //$db['online']['database'] = '******';
    $db['online']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
    $db['online']['dbprefix'] = '';
    $db['online']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
    $db['online']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
    $db['online']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
    $db['online']['cachedir'] = '';
    $db['online']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
    $db['online']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
    $db['online']['swap_pre'] = '';
    $db['online']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
    $db['online']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: Maybe you have used wrong credentials, Re-check the database credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Your default database seems to be using the `root` user without password. This is very unlikely to be the real credentials for your default database, so I'll assume they're wrong, leading to that issue (`default` is loaded by default because it is the default active group).

Assuming that you want `online` to be your active database instead of the default `default`, you should also set the following variable (also inside the `application/config/database.php` file):

```
$active_group = 'online';
```

And simply remove the `default` group (or even update it with the values of `online` and remove the `online` group if you want to avoid to set the `$active_group` variable).

---

Based on the comments, it seems that `default` is the database to be used and it contains the expected credentials. In this case, `online` shall not be automatically initialized, as it contains incorrect credentials, leading to the error shown in the question. To disable `online` autoinit, set it to FALSE:

```
$db['online']['autoinit'] = FALSE;
```

Or simply comment that line.

Also note that, in this case, `$active_group` shall not be set, or if it is, it should be set as:

```
$active_group = 'default';
```

Comment: I already changed the active group to default but now the interface shows blank without any content.


$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

Comment: Which one of the groups represent the correct credentials for the database? The ones defined on `default` or the ones defined on `online` ?

Comment: Its the one defined on the default

Comment: So, the `default` is using the user `root` **without password**, is that correct?

Comment: Please remove the `online` group from the file, or simply comment out the line `$db['online']['autoinit'] = TRUE;`